# Syntax of let in scheme

Tags: loops, scheme, let, named, chicken-scheme

I can't understand this use of `let` in an example I found. I'm using chicken scheme.

```
(let loop ()
    (print "hello world")
    (loop)
)
```

It's a simple infinite loop, it recursively calls itself, what I can't understand is the syntax. I know that the first argument must be a list of pairs `((<var[1]> <value[1]>)...(<var[n]> <value[n]))` and the other arguments are the body of the let.
So, why does this snippet work?

Comment: See 'named let'  -> http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_766

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a [named `let`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29), which is shorthand for a helper procedure, typically used for looping using recursion, with parameters that advance as the recursion progresses (although in you code no parameters were used). For example, this procedure:

```
(define (test)
  (let loop ((i 5))
    (cond ((<= i 0) 'ok)
          (else (print i)
                (loop (- i 1))))))
```

... is equivalent to this one:

```
(define (test)
  (define (loop i)
    (cond ((<= i 0) 'ok)
          (else (print i)
                (loop (- i 1)))))
  (loop 5))
```

Now you see that the snippet of code in the question is the same as writing this:

```
(define (loop)
  (print "hello world")
  (loop))

(loop)
```

Also notice that the name "loop" is just a convention, you might as well name it "iter" or "helper" or any other thing you fancy, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

It works because your statement about the first "argument" needing to be a list of binding is wrong. The syntax of `let` is like this:

```
(let name ((binding expression) ...)
  body ...)
```

The name is optional. You can have zero or more bindings.  How the macro sees it's named or not is by the fact that the bindings needs to be a list while the name absolutely needs to be an identifier. Without the name it's the same as:

```
((lambda (binding ...)
   body ...)
 expression ...)
```

However with the name it becomes:

```
((letrec ((name (lambda (binding ...)
                 body ...)))
   name)
 expression ...)
```

And of course `letrec` is defined in terms of `let`:

```
(letrec ((name expression) ...)
  body ...)
; ===
(let ((name 'undefined) ...)
  (let ((tmp expression) ...)
    (set! name tmp) ...)
  body ...)
```

Thus making the named let above turn into this:

```
(((lambda (name)
   ((lambda (tmp) (set! name tmp)) (lambda (binding ...) body ...))
   name)
  'undefined)
 expression ...)
```

Notice the trick that the name is not bound at the frame it's first called. It is returned and immediately called. Thus amoungst the expressions you can actually evaluate `name` from the free variables without the named `let` disturbing this:

```
(let ((name "sylwester"))
  (let name ((cur (list name))
             (n 2))
    (if (zero? n)
        cur
        (name (append cur cur) (- n 1)))))
; ==> ("sylwester" "sylwester" "sylwester" "sylwester")
```

Using `define` shadows that binding:

```
(let ((name "sylwester"))
  (define (name cur n) 
    (if (zero? n)
        cur
        (name (append cur cur) (- n 1))))

  (name (list name) 2))
; ==> (#<proc> #<proc> #<proc> #<proc>)
```

In the [R6RS report](http://www.r6rs.org/r6rs/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-2.html#node_toc_start) the [syntax for `let`](http://www.r6rs.org/r6rs/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_394) does not demonstrate the more complex named `let` but adds a reference to its description [elsewhere in the report](http://www.r6rs.org/r6rs/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.16). It's probably because named `let` might be overwhelming and confusing when you only want local bindings. This and that `define` are two different things top level and not are the most confusing parts of Scheme so it might be that the language would have been easier to grasp for beginners if these actually had different names rather than documented different places.

Comment: yes, the difference between `(letrec name (...) (name init))` and `((letrec name (...) name) init)`. so, `letrec` is actually the latter. interesting. --- you probably meant 

`(((lambda (name)
   ((lambda (tmp) name)
    (set! name (lambda (binding ...) body ...))))
  'undefined)
 expression ...)`

because otherwise if you allow for the implicit `begin` you could just have

`(((lambda (name)
   (set! name (lambda (binding ...) body ...))
   name)
  'undefined)
 expression ...)`

(http://codepad.org/rlKcHkm9)

Comment: (I meant, "named loop is the latter"...)

Comment: @WillNess My expansion is from the R5RS report and it doesn't allow use of the variable before the body. Thus evaluating all the expressions while the variables are unefined is preferred. Implemeters are urged to have a undefined value object and could signal an error should one of the expressions use the variables before the body. In R6RS I think your version is used and you are not allowed to use a later variable in the intimidate evaluation of the expressions. eg `(letrec ((a 10) (b a)) (list a b))` is not allowed in R5RS while `(letrec ((a b) (b 10)) (list a b))` is not allowed in either.

Comment: I was talking about one specific piece of code, for *named let* ("named loop" was itself a typo, in what itself was supposed to be a correction of a typo... hmm). I can't see any semantic difference between the three variants, as in http://codepad.org/Q5orPxAY.

Comment: @WillNess It's because there is only one `letrec` binding. The second you start doing `(letrec ((a 10) (b a)) (list a b))` it mysteriously works in your version but not in mine since it's designed to fail in R5RS.

Comment: again, I'm re-writing your code for *named let*, which is only *letrec*'ing in `name`: `(let name ((a 10)(b a)) (list a b))` is re-written  (with e.g. 2nd variant) as `(((lambda (name)
       ((lambda (tmp) name)
        (set! name (lambda (a b) (list a b)))))
      'undefined)
     10 a)` which fails. Same with the third. yes?

Comment: @WillNess You are right that there are no semantic differences and you can lift some of the lambdas for the simple case of named `let`. I did literally expand `letrec` which is designed to handle more than one procedure at a time and uses an extra set of temporary variables to throw errors in case any expression evaluates any of the variables ahead of the body evaluation. My example with `a` and `b` binding as `letrec` bindings (in place of `name`, only two of them) since that is where the difference between the expansion lies.